# Favorite Questions and Answers from 4th Quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2015 through December 31 2015 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**).

Also, this is totally *not* a duplicate of all the previous times I've done this.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/10/01)

Answer (score 9):

### Answers

This answer MUST get a mention:

- [Story where the number 3 is the monster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/31394)

This question used to be the highest-voted question on the Unanswered tab, by a factor of about 3, until Kyle Hale solved it with his first (and so far only) post on SFF. He's earned more rep from a single post than anyone else on SFF, by far, and this answer has earned more rep in bounties than any other answer **on the SE network**! The answering of this question was such a landmark in the history of the site that it inspired [its own blog post](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/10/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster-finally-answered/).

Although I'm not personally a fan of Star Wars, there have been some exceptional answers in this tag (along with a lot of very bad questions and answers, admittedly) in the last month, including the following gems from DVK:

- [How many times was Obi-Wan less than honest with Luke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/how-many-times-was-obi-wan-less-than-honest-with-luke/112543#112543)
- [Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112251/which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct/112253#112253)

In the obligatory 'tooting my own horn' section, I'm going to mention a couple of answers into which I put an enormous amount of time and effort without getting *that* much of a reward votes-wise:

- [What language does Neri from "Ocean Girl" speak?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107875/what-language-does-neri-from-ocean-girl-speak/108388#108388)
- [Was the location of the portal to Landover in "Magic Kingdom for Sale — SOLD!" an actual site in Virginia?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105430/was-the-location-of-the-portal-to-landover-in-magic-kingdom-for-sale-sold-a/105442#105442)

### Questions

This question about Tolkien generated some very interesting results; researching it, as well as reading the excellent answers from Wad Cheber and Jason Baker, taught me a huge amount:

- [Did Tolkien create any characters based on people he knew?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/did-tolkien-create-any-characters-based-on-people-he-knew)

This question deserves a special mention, as answering it enabled me to discover a new fantasy novel I hadn't heard of, which I've now bought myself for Christmas and started reading:

- [Which fairy tales are the stories in the first two Witcher books based on?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105639/31394)

(So answering questions on works you've never read can serve a practical purpose as well as helping others!)

Answer (score 6):

### Questions:

- [Does Lucius Malfoy have a wand inside his cane in the books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104833/does-lucius-malfoy-have-a-wand-inside-his-cane-in-the-books/104838#104838)

  It was fun to answer... and it showcases that films can in some cases have improvements over books.
- [Are the teachers at Hogwarts ever publicly intoxicated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109912/are-the-teachers-at-hogwarts-ever-publicly-intoxicated/109913#109913)

  Because I never before realized what a den of scum and villainly Hogwarts is.
- [Does "planting" have any biological impact on the Pequeninos (piggies) lifecycle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110188/does-planting-have-any-biological-impact-on-the-pequeninos-piggies-lifecycle/110200#110200)

  Because of awesome illustrations.
- [Do mathematicians have jobs in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110892/do-mathematicians-have-jobs-in-star-wars/110894#110894)

  Because I love the idea of ivory-tower Math professors in TGFFA.

  Plus, I *totally* ascribe to myself the credit for turning poor rambling question with -5 score into a good one (-5/+8).
- [Jane's gender in Ender's Game series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/janes-gender-in-enders-game-series/110898#110898)

  Because when I found the answer it was **so totally unexpected**.
- [Is there evidence to suggest that Supreme Leader Snoke is Darth Plagueis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110876/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-supreme-leader-snoke-is-darth-plagueis/111028#111028)

  Because it let me in on an awesome fan theory I was missing out on.
- [Potty breaks during The Force Awakens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111078/potty-breaks-during-the-force-awakens)

  ### Because this is the First Ever question on this site that is actually on-topic according to StackExcahange standards of "Please post **actual problems** you are facing", as our Site Tour insists

### Answers:

- Tooting my own horn, the canonical answer I compiled to [What is Orson Scott Card's position on discrepancies between various Enderverse books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109101/what-is-orson-scott-cards-position-on-discrepancies-between-various-enderverse/109102#109102) - which basically addresses about 10-30% of all *Ender's Game* questions on this site in one fell swoop
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109656/976 from @Hypnosifl, because he managed to completely beat my own answer, hands down.
- To honor Episode VII: The Lens Flares, the canonical answer to  [What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope/111225#111225) .
- This absolutely [delightful answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111997/976) from @rand al'thor on [What has been Alec Guinness's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111996/alec-guinness-attitude-toward-star-wars).

  "Fairy-tale rubbish" is my phrase of the year!

Comment: Now I need to thank you **twice**. Firstly for mentioning my Lucius Malfoy question, and secondly for not only promoting my Alec Guinness answer here but also making a meta question based on it. Have some upvotes! :-D

Answer (score 5):

### Answers

Praxis' answer to my 'Star Trek Selfie' question deserves a mention. +1 for going above and beyond with some original research

- **[Who are all the people in this “BEST. SELFIE. EVER!”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104907/20774)**

I thought my own answer to this one was nicely comprehensive

- **[Why was the saucer separation so rarely done on the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109870/20774)**

and proving to DVK that there's [no kill like overkill](http://media.giphy.com/media/136kOut0qvFB28/giphy.gif), quoting an answer from 7 different sources (including 3 different graphic novels of the same film, two different versions of the script as well as the FBI website)

- **[Why did Men in Black wear black suits?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107710/20774)**

---

### Questions

Not to blow my own trumpet, but if there was a special prize for "[*taking one for the team*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0vno.gif)" (28 downvotes and counting), I deserve it for asking ...

- **[What is Hermione Granger's ethnicity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105467/what-is-hermione-grangers-ethnicity)**

Answer (score 2):

This is really my favourite, as everyone drops into Yoda-talk so readily, with no questions asked.

- [On Dagobah, do what, did Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106339/3804)

Comment: Create a link, you did not.

Comment: Fixed it, you have

Comment: Hm, Mistakes you will make, if sleep you do not have.

Comment: This one, your favorite is? Surprised, you are, that questions, no one has? Ooo!

Comment: Answered it, I did. Thank you, I should. A Great Question badge, enderland will soon get.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite question was probably:

[What are the names of all the sci-fi vessels in this artwork?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107467/what-are-the-names-of-all-the-sci-fi-vessels-in-this-artwork)

I know that some users dislike these type of ID questions, but something fun happened with that one.

The answer was made into a community wiki and there was a strong collaboration between chatters and commenters to attempt to identify all the works. The artist was even contacted, but provided an incomplete list! So, we still haven't been able to identify all the vessels.

Working with the rest of the community to come up with guesses and confirmations for the guesses was a lot of fun, for me. It help bolster my sense of involvement with other active members, test my Sci-Fi knowledge and my Google-fu.